# Error in importing libraries of helper though helper is installed

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am using colab and already !pip install helper , but I facing the error AttributeError: module 'helper' has no attribute 'imshow' and also
AttributeError: module 'helper' has no attribute 'view_classify'
What is wrong with helper??

Answer (score 9):

to solve these issue run the following code at the top most cell of your notebook to install the helper file;

```
!wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/master/intro-to-pytorch/helper.py
```

Then restart your entire runtime for the notebook to load the file

Comment: worked for me!  go to Runtime menu->restart runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an `AttributeError`, it suggests that you've installed `helper` but a different version.

You can begin a Colab notebook with a block of only pip calls

```
!pip install helper==x.y.z
...
```

And you need to run it every time you start a new runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The helper library you are referring to is developed by Udacity.

Define a imshow function as following:

```
def imshow(image, ax=None, title=None, normalize=True):
  """Imshow for Tensor."""
  if ax is None:
      fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  image = image.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))

  if normalize:
      mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
      std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
      image = std * image + mean
      image = np.clip(image, 0, 1)

  ax.imshow(image)
  ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
  ax.tick_params(axis='both', length=0)
  ax.set_xticklabels('')
  ax.set_yticklabels('')

  return ax
```

Afterwards call:

> imshow("your_image");

You can call `image[0]` using

> `imshow(images[0].view(1, 28, 28));`

And you're good to go!

Reference:

https://github.com/udacity/DL_PyTorch/blob/master/helper.py#L42

Answer (score 0):

from udacity copy-paste the `view_classify` function and then use it.

```
def view_classify(img, ps, version="MNIST"):
    ''' Function for viewing an image and it's predicted classes.
    '''
    ps = ps.data.numpy().squeeze()

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,9), ncols=2)
    ax1.imshow(img.resize_(1, 28, 28).numpy().squeeze())
    ax1.axis('off')
    ax2.barh(np.arange(10), ps)
    ax2.set_aspect(0.1)
    ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(10))
    if version == "MNIST":
        ax2.set_yticklabels(np.arange(10))
    elif version == "Fashion":
        ax2.set_yticklabels(['T-shirt/top',
                            'Trouser',
                            'Pullover',
                            'Dress',
                            'Coat',
                            'Sandal',
                            'Shirt',
                            'Sneaker',
                            'Bag',
                            'Ankle Boot'], size='small');
    ax2.set_title('Class Probability')
    ax2.set_xlim(0, 1.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install:

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/3bd7dea850e936d8cb44adda8200e4e2b5d627e3/intro-to-pytorch/helper.py
```

then:

```
import importlib <br>
importlib.reload(helper)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].